# Reading and editing excel files with pandas

Tags: python, excel, pandas, xlsx, xlwt

So, I'm reading xlsx files and I need to select 3 specific columns, then rename them, and transfer the first 100 rows of each column to a new xlsx file, deleting them from the original one.

My code as of now is reading from a manually edited xlsx file, where I rename the columns, select the first 100 of them (except for the header), etc:

```
df = pandas.read_excel('test.xlsx', names=['date', 'value', 'source'])
df['date'] = pandas.to_datetime(df['date'], format='%b %d %Y.%f').astype(str)

print(df.head(5))
```

Which returns, as expected:

```
         date    value               source

0  2018-05-01      1                xxxxxxx
1  2018-05-01      1      xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
2  2018-05-02      1      xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
3  2018-05-02      1      xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
4  2018-05-03      1     xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
```

Is there a way to automatically read and edit the xlsx file with pandas? Other libs? I'm new to python and I'm really lost here :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Seems like you need 2 files output. One with the first hundred rows, another with the remainder. This is straightforward with [`pandas.DataFrame.iloc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html):

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_excel('test.xlsx', names=['date', 'value', 'source'])

df.iloc[:100].to_excel('out1.xlsx', index=False)
df.iloc[100:].to_excel('out2.xlsx', index=False)
```

Comment: thank you! this really helped me, now i'm wondering if there's a way to make a script to automate the excel editing part.

Comment: @GabrielFernandes, Not sure what that part requires unfortunately. You need to specify the precise transformations. Feel free to ask a [new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) if necessary.